# How do you extract the lat and lon from a GeoPt property?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm extending the GeoModel to store locations in the datastore so I can do geo-based searches more efficiently and I assumed I could use the GeoPt property to store latitude and longitude. And the storage has worked fine. But I'm at a complete loss as to how to extract the lat and lon from an entity.

I must be missing something simple but I can't actually find the documentation for the GeoPt type so I'm looking for help on supported methods.

```
class StopLocation(GeoModel):
    stopID = db.StringProperty()

def create(stopID,lat,lon):
    stop = StopLocation()
    stop.stopID = stopID
    stop.location = GeoPt(lat,lon)

latitude = stop.location???
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
latitude = stop.location.lat
longitude = stop.location.lon
```

Does that not work?

Comment: wow. the one thing i didn't try. my debugging was made worse by the fact that some objects didn't have a valid location. :(  thanks!